# Typing in JTextArea affects other components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea

I'm working on panel which has four components: a `label`, a `textfield` that is uneditable, another label and a `JTextArea`. These components are aligned vertically one after the other and I am using Box Layout for this panel. What I have noticed is that when I  type in the text area component, it shifts the labels character by character till it can't anymore. They labels initially are aligned to the left but as soon as I start typing they start moving to the right. I have tried so many other components but Box Layout seems to do what I want, I just have to fix this error. Any one ideas?
This is my panel code:

```
JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
Panel.add(new JLabel("just a label here"));
Panel.add(textFieldComponent);
Panel.add(new JLabel("just a label here"));
Panel.add(textAreaComponent);
```

Comment: `JTextArea` will "grow" to meet the requirements of the text (as apposed to something like `JTextField`.  To prevent it from effecting the layout of the container, place the `JTextArea` within a `JScrollPane`, this will allow it to grow inside the scroll pane. Check out [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use another `LayoutManager` e.g. `GridBagLayout` or

Place the `JLabel` in a panel with Horizontal `BoxLayout` (or `BorderLayout`) to actieve desired alignment.

Answer (score 3):

another alternative:

add the textAreaComponent to a JScrollPane (set the scrollPane's alignmentX to 0.0f)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well and I added: `textArea.setLineWrap(true)`. It prevented other objects from being pushed when you type in the field.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use another Layout. One of my personal favorite is [Forms from JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/). I've yet to see a Java Swing layout that comes anywhere close.